# the past Windows logo "Starting Windows" does not appear

Tags: windows-7

I have a Windows 7 Ultimate 32-bit that works perfectly except something. When it starts up, the past Windows logo "Starting Windows" does not appear instead the "Microsoft Corporation" logo appears. How can I fix this problem so that the Windows shows the previous "Starting windows" logo when starting?

Answer (score 0):

So you get the old Vista bootscreen instead of the new new one?

if this is the case, run this command and reboot:

```
bcdedit /set {current} locale LANG-Code
```

(replace LANG-Code with your language like en-US)

Comment: Thank you for your trying to help me. But it did not word. I used this command   bcdboot %WinDir% /l it-IT   in Command Prompt and worked fine.